# QGIS and QT library- code compilation problem

Tags: qgis, qt

So, I am trying to workout an GIS standalone application using QGIS and QT C++ Libraries on linux(ubuntu 15.04).
I am following this tutorial: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Code-Examples
Taking the first tutorial as an example, I am not able to compile it using the directions provided in the tutorial.
I have installed QGIS by: apt-get install qgis
I am not able to get through the "cmake .." step as it is saying it cannot find QGIS

The steps are: -

svn co https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/code_examples/1_hello_world_qgis_style
cd 1_hello_world_qgis_style

mkdir build
//optionally specify where your QGIS is installed (should work on all platforms)

//if your QGIS is installed to /usr or /usr/local you can leave this next step out

export LIB_DIR=/home/timlinux/apps

cmake ..

make

./timtut1

Please provide a solution.